# Can I catch an exception and restart my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, exception

When an exception is thrown inside a method in my app, I want the app to restart. How can I get this functionality? Can I use a try-catch block for that, and how?

Comment: If you can't recover from an exception, don't catch it!

Comment: You cannot force your app to restart. This is outside of the scope of your app and the system won't allow it.

Comment: To follow up on @JustSid's response.  You should only catch exceptions that you need to handle.  Don't catch exceptions trying to avoid bad situations - the bad situation will happen and you can't change it - only react (if you can or should)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't for a iOS iPad Java app?

Comment: Have you read the Exceptions Programming Guide, specifically the chapter called ["Controlling a Program’s Response to Exceptions"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/ControllingAppResponse.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000473-BBCHGJIJ)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't restart the app.

Your best alternative is to probably reset the *state* of the app. For example, you Application Delegate could have a method to setup and tear down the view controllers etc. and then another method to set them up from fresh again.

Note also that Apple will probably reject your app if you attempted to force it quit somehow.

Comment: You are right that you cannot restart the app, but Apple will not necessarily reject an app for force quitting. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html). It is highly discouraged because the user experience is crap -- the user will think the app crashed because it does not close with the smooth animation it would normally close with -- but I worked on an app once where my boss insisted I write a method to force quit the app and the update made it into the app store.

Answer (score 0):

You can not restart your app.

Apple would not allow you to do so.

Try to catch your error throw it, but restarting NO.